# Project Euler N# 8 JAVA

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, logic

I am trying to solve [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) and I think I am in the right track but for some reason the program does not run in a specific condition. 
This is the code:

```java
public class Eight {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String set = "731671765313306249192251196744265747423"
                + "553491949349698352031277450632623957831801698"
                + "480186947885184385861560789112949495459501737958"
                + "331952853208805511125406987471585238630507156932909"
                + "632952274430435576689664895044524452316173185640309871"
                + "112172238311362229893423380308135336276614282806444486645"
                + "238749303589072962904915604407723907138105158593079608"
                + "66701724271218839987979087922749219016997208880937"
                + "7665727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752"
                + "243525849077116705560136048395864467063244157221"
                + "55397536978179778461740649551492908625693219784"
                + "686224828397224137565705605749026140797296865"
                + "241453510047482166370484403199890008895243450"
                + "6585412275886668811642717147992444292823086346567481391912316282458617866458"
                + "3591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165"
                + "8960408071984038509624554443629812309878799272442849091888458015616609791913387549920052"
                + "4063689912560717606058861164671094050775410022569831552000559357297257163626956188267042"
                + "8252483600823257530420752963450";

        int initialIndex = 0;
        int lastIndex = 4;
        int finale = 0;

        for (;last <= set.length() - 1; initialIndex++, lastIndex++)
        {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(set.substring(initialIndex, lastIndex));
            int result = 1;

            while (num > 0)
            { 
                int digit = num % 10;
                result *= digit;
                num /= 10;
            }

            if (result > finale) 
                finale = result;
        } //end for 

        System.out.println(finale);
    }
}
```

When lastIndex equals 4, the result I get is 5832, which is the same result as Project Euler gives you as an example. But when Im trying to run this program with 13 numbers instead of 4, I get an exception and the program does not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 13 digit string will exceed the maximum allowable size of an int. Use `Long.parseLong` and change `num` from `int` to `long`. I did it, and got the following when I used 13 digits: 2091059712

Answer (score 3):

Your issue begins here:

```
            int num = Integer.parseInt(set.substring(initialIndex, lastIndex));
```

When you set `lastIndex` as 13, the number you are trying to take out of the string is 7,316,717,653,133. In your code, you are trying to parse that `String` as an `int`, which has a maximum value of `2^31` 2,147,483,647.

You can fix your problem by making any variable you expect to excede 2^31 a different integral data type, like a `long`.